# magento 1.9: Update product images with dataflow on magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, dataflow

I am `updating` all of the `product images on my site`. However when I change the `base`, `small` and `thumbnail` images in the `dataflow` `CSV` it adds the new image but keeps the old one as well as a second image for the product.

I don't want the old image associated with the product at all.

Is this possible with dataflow?

Thanks :-)

Comment: for this you can create custom script loop down your all sku and take code from here then import your image again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709496/magento-programmatically-remove-product-images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you have server access you should delete all rows on these tables :

```
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
```

then delete all images in  this directory :

```
media/catalog/product
```

don't forget to reindex

cheers :)